# Is $\exists xP(x)\lor\exists xQ(x)$ the same as $\exists xP(x)\lor\exists yQ(y)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

Very simple question:

Is $\exists xP(x)\lor\exists xQ(x)$ the same as $\exists xP(x)\lor\exists yQ(y)$?

Thank you.

Comment: yes (but in [metalanguage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage) no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are in the same domain of discourse, then yes. Otherwise, it remains ambiguous.